# Failed to resolve com.github.bumptech.glide (build.gradle)

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting this error:
**ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app**
I tried adding stories library into my app and this happened.
The library is Status Stories
The other library for image loading is from bumptech.
My build.gradle(Module: app) file also it says that it cannot be synced:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ozurak.mk"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1476
        versionName "1.4.7.6"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        ignoreWarnings true //false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //Intro Screen
    implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
    //scrolling tab hide top
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.6.0'


    //emoji disabler
    implementation 'com.xw.repo:xedittext:2.1.0@aar'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

    //android
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    //circle image view
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

    //like button
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'

    //image loader
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'

    //ExifInterface support
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:26.+"

    //image picker
    implementation 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.2.1'

    //button
    implementation 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.2'

    //image loader
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //image scroll 7/8/2018
    implementation 'com.github.Q42:AndroidScrollingImageView:1.3.3'
    //dropdown list
    implementation 'com.github.JayFang1993:DropDownMenu:v0.9'
    //zoom
    implementation 'com.ablanco.zoomy:zoomy:1.1.0'
    //stories
    implementation 'com.github.RahulJanagouda:StatusStories:1.0.1'



    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you using kotlin

Comment: @Niyas No I am using pure Java code

Comment: In app gradle, do you have these repositories; maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }, maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }, mavenCentral().

Comment: @ahmet I didn't had the second one i think it resolved the issue

Comment: @SuperGeekyDude Post your repositories block in the top level file